# Using Selenium webdriver and Requests together in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I like the simplicity of Requests, however when dealing with logins or JS, Selenium webdriver makes life much easier.

How could I combine these 2?

I tried installing [selenium-requests](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-requests/), but this doesn't work and returns permission errors.

Can I login with Selenium and then pass that info to requests in order to make simple GET and POST requests?

Or have I maybe overlooked something and is there an option to just do POST requests using Selenium?

Comment: Maybe you should post the permission error you encountered when using selenium-requests? You know, when a package fails to do the single thing it was designed to do, that is a pretty big red flag.